# how to convert ed25519 keys in pgsql database and retrieve them back

Tags: python, encryption

I want to store the `Public` and `Private` keys in `pgsql database` and then when required want to retrieve them back.

I tried converting it ,storing and retrieving it from database but this results in error:
            `TypeError: Odd-length string`

```
python testenc.py "TEST" 
"5b69ecf0fb808693e6fdf6514fd8f1eca20b96e407ec78681269b24463d2cc0" 
"3d4b091ff086660c8adfd3318d43563a2befb85619bb4422161a4e9ae0837131"
```

**Input Message is :** `TEST`

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

```
File "testenc.py", line 31, in <module>
    skbob = pickle.loads(binascii.unhexlify(sys.argv[2]))
```

**TypeError:** `Odd-length string`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows:

1) use library pickle for this.
2) Use a socket communication and after receiving data on socket use pickle.load(received string) to maintain the key intact.

3) While sending data on socket "use pickle.dump(string)" so that data/Key remains intact.